# What is the meaning of " intrajudicial"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm using the website Vocabulary.com to enlarge my vocals. Here is the question I really stuck on:

> Fill the blank
>
> An intrajudicial spat highlights a debate over the right to privacy and the ________ of cameras in the courtroom.
>
> (1) Defiance
>
> (2) humility
>
> (3) propriety
>
> (4) breadth

The right one is (3)propriety.

Here is my confusion:

(1) What is the meaning of "intrajudicial"?

Google works for  "extrajudicial"   which means: 
(i)  not forming a valid part of regular legal proceedings

(ii)  delivered without legal authority

I know there must be something opposition between two words but I still can't guess a appropriate meaning for this one and so get no idea what "intrajudicial spat" stands for.

(2) Please tell me the whole meaning of sentence.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Intrajudicial*, I would suggest, means *between members of the legal profession*.

Comment: What I don't understand is what does "interjudicial" have to do with choosing the right answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this term has a specific meaning within the law, and should be migrated or reposted to law.SE.

Comment: "Intrajudicial" could also mean "within a certain judicial district." In the US there are 94 of 'em. See https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+many+judicial+districts+are+there+in+the+us%3F&form=EDGNTC&qs=PF&cvid=fadff102752f4dc38ba42e5451853dc2&pq=how+many+judicial+districts+are+there+in+the+us%3F&elv=AXXfrEiqqD9r3GuelwApulrYtuZ5tIGtQGvo5YhUGvRzqaCWEjowi9M4GR8EgUirt*IGoPSb*P3KT8OWmfkowZemPA6tX8FNGVGVkEvQGHQC. Various issues and controversies crop up all the time within those 94 districts. They do not, however, crop up at the same time in each district. Hence, "intra-" meaning within a district.

Comment: @jimm101 Really? Do you have a source for this claim? I don't think *intrajudicial* is a legal term of art; I think it's just an ordinary compound with the prefix *intra*, like *intra-agency*, *intradepartmental*, *intranet*, or *intramural*. I could be convinced otherwise by evidence though.

Comment: @deadrat I think the real issue is (as I commented above) what the word has to do with choosing the right answer. The question is not well asked and Jimm101 could have closed it as "lack of research". I didn't vote to close it though.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence seems to indicate that there is a disagreement, spat, or 'lack of unanimity' between various judicial authorities over a certain issue.

In this context, the word "intrajudicial" may just seem to indicate that the disagreement is ONLY within the judiciary (or judicial authorities) at the moment and does not involve other people. "[Intra](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intra-)" is a prefix here and means the following:

> on the inside; within

[Oxford Online Dictionaries]

Comment: Hello, Monzoor. A valid answer on ELU will almost always carry supporting evidence.

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth said, I edited your answer and deleted a sentence with a typo. Please review it and try to follow this format when you answer a question next time. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

*The Compact Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary* (1985)—the two-volume edition with tiny type and an accompanying magnifying glass—has no entry for ***intrajudicial***. Nor does the term appear in *Black's Law Dictionary*, fourth edition (1968). So my guess is that intrajudicail is a neologism and that the writer intends for "intrajudicial spat" to refer to a dispute among judges serving on the same court or panel—different judges on the U.S. Supreme Court, for example.

Presumably, an ***interjudicial*** spat would involve judges from different but co-equal jurisdictions—say the fifth and ninth circuit courts of appeal—disagreeing on some point of law.

Comment: Presumably, *interjudicial* would (or at least could) involve judges and administrators from the entire judicial branch. Especially as the debate is not about a point of law, but about judicial policy.